# jQuery generates PHP inside HTML Comments (WORDPRESS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have WordPress installed on my site and am currently editing the theme.

I have appended a list item to the end of the generated navigation menu. Inside of the list item is a block of PHP that calls the search form.

The problem I run into is, while the list item is appended, the block of PHP is placed inside of HTML comment tags. I don't know why and have tried several ways to get rid of it.

```
<li>
    <!--?php get_search_form(); ?-->
</li>
```

The JavaScript I used to append the list item and search bar is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    $("header nav .nav-menu").append("<li><?php get_search_form(); ?></li>");
});
```

WordPress generates the information in a header template using this:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="wrapper2">
                <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></button>
                <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>

            </div>
        </nav>
```

From my googling my assumption is I'm nesting PHP within PHP, but I haven't been able to fix it.

The PHP variable that stores the search form HTML is:

```
$form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">
                <div>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '</label>
                    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeHolder="Enter your search here..." />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr_x( '&#59394;', 'submit button' ) .'" />
                </div>
            </form>';
```

I would appreciate any help or insight since I'm not used to working with PHP or WordPress themes.

Comment: Do you have a searchform.php in your theme folder?

Comment: The function goes to that file first.  What is in the file is it the commented code?

Comment: I got it you are missing an echo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I would like to thank Playground for explaining why my idea of using JavaScript would not work.

Also thank you to w3bmak3r for telling me about the external JS file and the link to the search_form function on the wordpress site.

My goal was to append a search bar at the end of the navigation list. I accomplished this by adding a list item at the beginning of the navigation list.
I found the information [here on wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_a_Word_at_the_Beginning_of_the_Menu).

From:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
```

To:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="menu-site" class="nav-menu" style=""><li class="thesearchform">' . get_search_form() . '</li>%3$s</ul>' ) ); ?>
```

Next, I used jQuery to append the first list item as the last child:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    
    var theSearchForm = $("header nav li.thesearchform");
    $("header nav .nav-menu").append(theSearchForm).find(theSearchForm).append($("header nav .searchform"));
});
```

So yeah, this worked. Thank you both for helping me.

Edit:
If anyone knows how I can insert `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` into the wp_nav_menu, it would help me make it readable.

Edit, nevermind, I figured it out and edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, what you are trying to do here....

Your Javascript doesn't make any sense. Javascript is executed on the client side, while PHP is server-side, meaning the moment your javascript runs, appending a php call to html, will do nothing other then putting text in it, not executing anything....

any php code has to go in the template, and not in any kind of javascript, unless it's some data you are passing to a javascript variable

Comment: I am not one to down vote an answer but this does not help.  and there are a lot of wordpress themes that do it this way

Comment: I assumed the code would fire normally like HTML tags do.

Comment: I didn't downvote this post... In what world do you live in, where php code fires, after the dom is build? His code starts with $(document).ready(), you can't append php code to html and expect it to run...

Comment: All his php code is doing is rendering markup.. Lots of themes do this.. I feel kind of dirty every time I see it and use it but eh...

Comment: I wasn't talking about the third box, i was talking about the second one, he is injecting php code via javascript and that doesn't work!

Comment: The php will be called and rendered when the page is created.  Server side logic is rendered first.  So before Javascript even sees it, it will be the markup of their form.  When you inspect or view source on a php file you do not see the php code you see the render markup.  This is also what client side Javascript sees.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Check to see if you have a getsearchform.php file.  If you do then this is overriding that function.  get_search_form() grabs from this file first.

In the root of your theme add or change the file searchform.php.

In this file add the code for the form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">
          <div>
               <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '</label>
               <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeHolder="Enter your search here..." />
               <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr_x( '&#59394;', 'submit button' ) .'" />
          </div>
</form>
```

You are also missing an echo before the get_search_form();

Your JS should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    $("header nav .nav-menu").append("<li><?php echo get_search_form(); ?></li>");
});
```

Lastly your JS is in a .php file right?  This will all work and is done in some themes if you can though you should try to avoid mixing your php and javascript.  But this should work.

See this documentation:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form#Theme_Form

Comment: The JS is not in a php file. Also using echo currently still put the php in a comment. I will try what you put.

Comment: what file is the js in exactly?  it can not be in a .js file.  but if you put the code in your footer.php or something it should work

Comment: In a .js (javascript) file located externally.

Comment: Oh yeah that will not work.. move the code to your footer.php